# Two yellow cards before one is shown

Tags: rules, football

Is it possible for a player to be sent off for two yellow card offences before the first yellow card has time to be shown? e.g. where the referee plays advantage after the first offence.

Comment: As it seems, the situation exactly this happened in the 2015 match between Northern Ireland and Hungary: https://www.skysports.com/football/news/12019/9983083/northern-irelands-chris-baird-receives-bizarre-red-card

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Another example happened in the German [Bundesliga](https://www.fussballdaten.de/bundesliga/2013/3/hannover-bremen/), when a player scored the winning goal and immediately got two yellow cards. One for taking his shirt off, one for climbing the fence. Both are mandatory yellow cards (at least in the Bundesliga), i.e. there is no leeway for the referee.

Comment: I appreciate that final sentence is an attempt to clarify why the referee did this, but it isn't entirely correct. [Law 5, Section 2, Paragraph 1](http://theifab.com/laws/the-referee-2018/chapters/decisions-of-the-referee-2018) gives the referee discretion to not apply a formal sanction if it is in the spirit of the game to not do so. Whether both are both separate offences is also up for debate - in most cases, taking a shirt off and climbing the fence are continuations of the same excessive celebration, which is the offence that the player should be cautioned for.

Comment: In light of this, I think that the answer would be stronger with just the first two sentences.

Comment: This is exactly the reason included these sentences. Normally, a referee would not give two yellow cards in this situation, as it feels against thespiritinof the rules. But the FIFA rules might be amended by national FAs. And in the bundesliga, there was (maybe still is) no leeway in these cases. In fact, the referee expressed he was sorry, but that he had no choice.

Comment: National FAs cannot amend the IFAB Laws of the Game. They can give advice, but in no way is this binding per se. However, since the same people selecting referees are the ones giving the advice, referees in national leagues will normally follow it blindly. Either way, the referee still had the power to give a single caution here without risking having the game replayed due to an error in Law.